# match word '90%' using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want word '90%' to be matched with my String "I have 90% shares of this company".

how can I write regular expression for same?

I tried something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b90\\%\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
    | Pattern.MULTILINE);
  Matcher m = p.matcher("I have 90% shares of this company");
  while (m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

but no luck.

Can any one thow some lights on this?

Many thanks,
Archi

Comment: I suggest you format the code and tag it with Java as well.

Comment: What's the point of using RegEx if you're just searching for a fixed string?

Comment: @Kenny: with regex you can specify a word-boundary, so it won't match "990%" (not that I expect that's often a problem here).

Answer (score 4):

There is no `\b` word boundary in the middle of `"% "`; that's why your pattern fails.

Use this pattern instead:

```
"\\b90%"
```

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

So between two characters, a `\b` exists only between a `\W` and a `\w` (in either order).

Both `'%'` and `' '` are `\W`, so that's why there's no `\b` between them in `"% "`.

Answer (score 1):

The parens "capture" the match:

```
/^.*(90%).*$/g
```

Comment: /(90%)/ is a more succint way of doing this in this case.

Comment: This matches `999990%` (but indeed captures only `90%`), which doesn't seem to be what OP intended.